# How to pass values to parameter to call stored procedure from MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

This is MVC C#. I have stored procedure called **uspMarket_test**. I need to pass parameter called **session** to this SP.

I am writhing this code in controller . Here **sess** contains values of session which i am passing.

```
public ActionResult Index(string sess)
    {

        var permissions = new Accept();
        permissions.permissions(sess);



        return View();
    }
```

In terms.cs, i am using :

```
public void permissions(string sess)
    {
        using (var ctx2 = new market_Entities())
        {
         //Here i need to assign sess = session, so value of sess will be equal to session string.But dont know how to do this.

      ctx2.uspMarket_test(new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(int)),"session", new ObjectParameter("Login",typeof(short)));
            ctx2.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Here problem i am having is, second parameter session. I need to assign **sess** value to **session** parameter, so when i pass session to SP, it will take sess values. but i dont know how to assign this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Session["YourIndexName"] = sess;
```

or

```
Session[0] = sess; //using whatever zero based index is appropriate for you.
```